# Scaling Bitmap with Android

Tags: android, image, scale, interpolation

So I'm developing an photo editing application for Android and I was just wondering if anybody knows what kind of scaling algorithm (bicubic/bilinear interpolation, etc.) is used by the Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(...) method because developer.android.com does not give any information concerning this.
[A link to the documentation of the method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)

Answer (score 3):

It's bilinear interpolation with a magnification limit. When exceeding that limit, all additional magnification is done by nearest neighbor interpolation.